# How can I get ETC(estimated time for completion ) for SSRS report using Reporting Services 2010 web service

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have hosted my reports on SSRS server and those are Time Driven Subscriptions. I'm getting all the information using ListSubscriptions & GetSubscriptionProperties. But to get each reports ETC(estimated time for completion) I have to extract match data and then apply logic to get how much time report took for the execution.

Is there any method/way to get how much time report took for the execution?

Help appreciated.

Thanks
Chandra

Comment: Have you looked in ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog, it contains times for query times and rendering as well as total report execution time.

Comment: Thanks Alan, Actually I could use the DB in this case but I dont have access to Report server DB